# How to Retrieve Device Key for ConfirmDevice API with Cognito Amplify in Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplify-flutter, flutteramplify

I'm working on a Flutter project where Cognito Amplify is handling authentication. I'm trying to implement a feature that requires me to call the confirmDevice API, but I'm facing an issue regarding the retrieval of the device key. It appears that the device key is not readily accessible through the provided user details or session information. I've checked the `SignInDetails` of the user as well as the `CognitoAuthSession`, but the device key is not available. Could someone provide guidance on how to obtain the device key using Cognito Amplify within the Flutter framework? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.